# Using For loop with Multi-threading in Java 1.6

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use For loop with multi-threading in Java 1.6. I tried to use streams but apparently it was added in Java 1.8, so i tried to useExecutorService and Future but i can't make it work.

What i want is just make this code multi-threaded with fixed number of threads.

```
for (ExampleType ex : exampleData) {
    exampleFunction(ex.getSomeData());
}
```

What i tried and didn't work, found it somewhere from google

```
final ExecutorService testExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // just 10 thread
final List<Future<?>> executeDatas = new ArrayList<List>();

for (ExampleType ex : exampleData) {
    Future<?> executeData = testExecutor.submit(() -> {
        exampleFunction(ex.getSomeData());
    });
    executeDatas.add(executeData);
}

for (Future<?> executeData : executeDatas) {
    executeData.done(); // do i need to write stuff here? i don't have done() function
}
```

It probably would've worked but says diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6. Yeah i'm not sure how to handle from here and been stuck. Any help is appreciated

Comment: That code won't work in Java 6 because of the lambda. You'd need to write it an anonymous class.

Comment: `executeData.get();` to wait for the results in the order you submitted them. If you want them in completion order, use a `CompletionService`.

Comment: Why even use Java 1.6? It is more than 10 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, noone shows the transformed code, so I'll do it:

```
final ExecutorService testExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final List<Future<?>> executeDatas = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

for (ExampleType ex : exampleData) {
    Future<?> executeData = testExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            exampleFunction(ex.getSomeData());
        }
    });
    executeDatas.add(executeData);
}

for (Future<?> executeData : executeDatas) {
    // calling get in loop to effectively wait for all the futures to finish
    executeData.get();
}
```

Three changes are made:

1. `ArrayList<List>` replaced with with `ArrayList<Future<?>>`
2. Lambda replaced with anonymous class instantiation
3. `.done()` changed to `.get()` to wait for all the futures to finish execution